# ArrayList of array delete element and split method

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of arrays and i changed "5" to " 12 6" Then I concatenated "3" with " 12 6".

[2,4,6] [1,3,5] => [2,4,6] [1,3, 12 6] => [2,4,6] [1,3 12 6, 12 6]

Now i want to remove " 12 6"  and my arraylist to become [2,4,6] [1,3 12 6]

Then i want to make [1,3 12 6] to [1,3,12,6]

And my list look like [2,4,6] [1,3,12,6]

I have no idea if it's possible and how to do it(maybe there is another way). I have to delete one number and add two numbers

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String [] arr1 = {"2","4","6"};
    String [] arr2 = {"1","3","5"};
    list.add(arr1);
    list.add(arr2);      

    for (String[] ss : list)
    {
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ss));
        for ( i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
          if (ss[i] == "5") {                                              
            System.out.println("Yes"); 
            ss[i] = " 12 6";  
            ss[i-1] = ss[i-1] + String.valueOf(ss[i]);  
          }
        }
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ss));
    }
```

Comment: I absolutely have no idea of what you are trying to do here..Your algorithm is strange and it's probably not the best solution.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but I'd strongly advise using `List`s instead of arrays. As the answer from DCS_Kurtis_IT_Manager indicates, `List`s are much more flexible than arrays. Also, I don't know why you want to represent integers as `String`s. In short, replace `List<String[]>` with `List<List<Integer>>` and you will find this much easier.

Comment: Also, I noticed that you checked for `ss[i] == "5"` in an `if statement`. Never compare objects with the `==` in java, only compare objects with `.equals()`. Primitives (numbers and enums) are great for comparing with `==`, because `==` compares the instances of the objects, and numbers and enums will always be the same object, while comparing the String `ss[i]` and `"5"` are two different objects.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not dynamic in size therefore you cannot take your original size of 3 and remove a value to the size of 2. If you made them into array lists, It could be done with simple remove() and if statements

Also, I am curious as to what you are doing with this algorithm, I feel like what ever you are doing there is a better way.

A generic tip I tell most beginner programmers, is to think of the algorithm you wish to do step by step. Every time you do some sort of calculation/step in your brain, write it down. When you are finished, if you have not skipped anything you have the easiest (for you) algorithm to understand.

"It is perfectly acceptable to keep integers as Strings if you are not doing any sort of calculation on them. In that sense they are being used as strings, and should be kept as such." -My Boss

** I would add a comment but I do not have 50 reputation (seems silly that you need 50)
You need to explain what you are attempting to do clearly you are short handing your explanations, and it is making it difficult to assist you.

Comment: I have A1= null;
       A2 = {14}
       A3 = {16}
       A4 = {4}
       A5 = {10,5,13}
 ... A10

And B1 = {14, 5, 16}
    B2 = {4,10}
    B3 = {13, 15}
    B4 = {3, 12}
    B5 = {11, 6}
 ... B10

And i need 9 lists

L1 = B1;
L1 = {14,5,16}
for i=2; i<=n-1; i++ replace Ai with Bi

example: 

i=2 
A2 = 14

=> 
L2 = {4,10,5,16}
 
Here is a small part of the algorithm of locating a point in a PSLG(Planar straight-line graph)
Slab Method: Plane Sweep